# Google maps autocomplete not working in Django MultiFormView

Tags: python, django, google-maps

I'm working with the library [django-google-maps](https://pypi.org/project/django-google-maps/) to create an address field for properties. For displaying the form, I'm using the following code:

```
class PropertyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ['address', 'owned_since',
                  'geolocation', 'bought_for', 'property_type']
        widgets = {
            'address':  map_widgets.GoogleMapsAddressWidget(attrs={'data-map-type': 'roadmap', 'data-autocomplete-options': json.dumps({
                'componentRestrictions': {'country': 'us'}
            })}),
            'geolocation': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'owned_since': forms.DateInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            }),
            'bought_for': CustomMoneyWidget(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

It works perfectly in a generic UpdateView and in the admin interface, but when I try to include it in a [MultiFormView](https://github.com/TimBest/django-multi-form-view), the map does not show and the autocomlete isn't working either, it behaves like a simple CharField. There are also no errors or messages in the console.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that when mixing with `MultiFormView`, the name of the form in the context is under `forms.your_form`. The solution is simply to add `{{forms.your_form.media}}` in the head tags.